# Waiting for dispatch in thunks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I need to wait until dispatch in thunks is done. After that, I have to set state of hook to true.

Here is my service:

```
   export const loadSearchInfoAsync = (product_id: string) => {
      return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
        SearchService.getSearchInfo(product_id)
          .then((response) => {
            if (response) {

              // Wait until this dispatch is done
              dispatch(searchInfoLoadSuccess(response.data));

            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            if (error) {
              dispatch(appErrorState(error.response));
            }
          });
      };
    };
```

And here is state which has to be updated after that dispatch

```
  const handleScan = (data: string | null) => {
    if (!proceed && data) {

      // After this dispatch make setProceed true
      dispatch(loadSearchInfoAsync(data));
      setProceed(true);
    }
  };
```

Comment: So `data` needs to be set (i.e. your thunk has been called) before `setProceed` should be switched to `true`?

Comment: Yes exactly. Dispatch must be successful first, and then setProceed should be set to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help you

```
const loadSearchInfoAsync = (product_id: string, onSuccess, onFailure) => {
return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  SearchService.getSearchInfo(product_id)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response) {

        // Wait until this dispatch is done
        dispatch(searchInfoLoadSuccess(response.data));
        onSuccess()
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error) {
        dispatch(appErrorState(error.response));
        onFailure()
      }
    });
};
```

};

```
 const loadSearchInfoPromise = (product_id: string) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  dispatch(loadSearchInfoAsync(product_id, resolve, reject))
}
```

}

```
 const handleScan = async (data: string | null) => {
if (!proceed && data) {

  // After this dispatch make setProceed true

  await loadSearchInfoPromise(data).then(() => {
    setProceed(true);
  })
}
```

};

Comment: A dump of code is rarely as useful (and therefore worthy of an upvote) as an explanation of what you've changed in the code and why. See [answer].

Comment: I'm facing this problem for 2 days. Thanks for your answer, really helped me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you could probably just move your proceed code into an  effect and wait for a response on that?

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (data.length) { // or do whatever check here to see if it's not empty
    setProceed(true);
  }
}, [data])
```